# PHP foreach array of directories get error Notice: Array to string conversion on line 45

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Below is a script that finds sub directories and stores them in an array. 
When I use a foreach to step through the directory I get and eror convert array to string. 
I has tseted the foreach variable using gettype, and is shown to be a string.

```
            $dir = '/Video/Movies';     //base directory for search
            $ar_dirlist[] = [];         // array to store directory list
            //Function to walk directories and store subdirectories in an array
            function listFolderFiles($dir){
                global $ar_dirlist;
                $ffs = scandir($dir);
                // $ffs = sortbydir($dir, $ffs);
                unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
                unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);
                // prevent empty ordered elements
                if (count($ffs) < 1)
                {
                    echo '<br />';
                    return;
                }
                //parse scandir output in array $ffs
                foreach($ffs as $ff){
                    $phpfile = $dir . '/' . $ff;
                    if(is_dir($phpfile))
                    {
                        $ar_dirlist[] = $phpfile;
                        listFolderFiles($phpfile); //if directory recurse

                    }

                }
            }
            listFolderFiles($dir);
            foreach ($ar_dirlist as $tmpdir) {
                echo '<h3>' . $tmpdir . '</h3>';   // This is line with error
                //echo '<br />';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, it was the way I had initialized the array. I should have used null, and not [];

Answer (score 0):

i think you might be wrong in initializing `$ar_dirlist` array. it should be:

```
$ar_dirlist = [];
```